# How to handle animations on divs with angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I've been reading up on animation with AngularJS and from my understanding, the ngAnimate module can be used out of the box with standard Angular directives. I also understand that css animation is encouraged as the first port of call.

In order to learn Angular, I created a dummy project and I wanted to have a panel fade in when a button is clicked and then have it fade out when clicked again. Since I come from a jquery background, my typical approach would be to use something along the lines of:

```
$('button').on('click', function() {

  // If box is visible
  $('.box').stop().fadeOut();


  // If box is hidden
  $('.box').stop().fadeIn();
});
```

However with Angular I'm not quite sure what the best way of accomplishing the same thing is. I've had a look at some tutorial vids and [this demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/BPWPZgWWyoxrCKFfyhmD) is the approach I've come up with. The problem I'm having however is that if I rapidly click on the button it seems to glitch and the animations get screwed up. I suppose the questions I'm asking are a) Is my approach to fading in/out an element a wise one (since I really want to adopt an Angular mindset) and b) How do I replicate jquery's .stop() ie. how do I stop an animation to start another one instead?

I'm struggling a little in understanding how to do animations with Angular since it was so simple with jquery :-)

Thanks

Comment: yeah,it was so simple to guess messy in jquery.But angular is not jQuery,so stop thinking about the jQuery way.https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/animations

Comment: To answer your `b)` question, if you use CSS animations with `ngAnimate`, you don't need to worry about "stopping" the animation because the browser will just handle any transitions that are currently occurring. And they're almost always more performant than jquery/javascript animations.